# What is this seal script character? (Character identified: 矦)

Tags: character-identification, seal

[image]

Can someone help me to identify this seal character.
I have 3 others seals with this character, always in the 3rd position. Un the 3rd character it is slightly different but I think it is the same.
Thanks for your help
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be treated as “侯” (u+4faf):

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=侯](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E4%BE%AF)

a severely distorted version to fit a circle

actually, it’s “矦” (u+77e6), the right component of the “侯”

[image]